# How to convert date format like 1170101 to mysql date format 2017-01-01?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Hi I have a date column in mysql (actually it's SQuirreL, but basically it's mysql),and the data type of this column is integer and has format like 1170101, anyone knows how can I convert it to mysql date format 2017-01-01 in mysql so mysql can recognize it?

Thank you.

Comment: how come 117 become 2017?

Comment: What does a date before 2000 look like?  Does `0990101` equate to `1999-01-01`?

Comment: I think it's an excel date format which assume time starts from year 1900

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
date(concat(1170101 + 19000000))
```

You can test using this sql.

```
select date(concat(1170101 + 19000000));
```

Comment: My pleasure! ^^.

Comment: A follow up question, I write "select date(concat(mydate+19000000)) as Ndate, salesamount from xxtable" if I want to write "where year(Ndate)=2017" I need to write "where year(date(concat(mydate+19000000)))=2017" Is that correct? Is there any way that I can just use Ndate for the date(concat blah blah formula?

Comment: ... where year(date(concat(mydate+19000000)))=2017 is right.  or you can write this,           year(concat(1170101 + 19000000))

Comment: ok, but I still need to type in the formula, I can't use a word like Ndate to refer to this formula right...?

Comment: you can't use alias in where clause completely..., Your choice can be a user-defined procedure.